# Is for loop indexing possible with negative values

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I would like to run a for loop over a sequence of values and preform a simple calculation. So for example, here I have a vector `x` ranging form -10 to 10. I'd like to calculate the number of values less than a given value in `x`.

`x<-seq(-10,10,1)`

`nums<-vector()`

`for (i in x) {
    nums[i] <- length( which(x < i))
}`

However as coded this for loop only indexes over the positive values in `x` and returns:

`nums` = `11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`

Rather than what I would like to see:

`nums` = `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`

Comment: In R you can run a `for` loop over most anything - integers, negative values, strings, doesn't much matter. But you should probably learn what `nums[i]` means when `i` is negative... the indexing rules for vectors have nothing to do with for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R in principle is designed to avoid loops where ever possible. In addition to that there are some syntax errors in your code...

If you want to loop along a vector you need to use `i in seq_along(x)` not `i in x`. A solution to your problem would be indexing the vector directly

```
    for (i in seq_along(x)){ 
      nums[i] <- sum(x < x[i])
    }
```

Edit: The reason you only looped over the positive values is that `i in x` starts indexing by -10 wich works for comparing x against i but not to asignment your start asigning at `nums[-10]` which is not really suitable...

Comment: I'm not sure it's an error in the code per se... the tweak I added works the same as yours answer  BUT yours is faster: `0.023` vs `0.017`

Answer (score 1):

You are using negative index for your vector, try something like:

```
nums <- NULL
for (i in x) {
    nums <- c(nums, length( which(x < i)))
}
```

Or:

```
nums <- NULL
for (i in x) {
    nums <- c(nums, sum(x < i))
}
```

Actually a better approach or more `R` way to do this would be use function from `apply` family.

```
sapply(x, function(ele) sum(x < ele))
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

`x<-seq(-10,10,1)`

`nums<-vector()`

`for (i in x){
    nums[i+11] <- length( which(x < i))
}`